# What is the difference between [add] and [addition]? Are they synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Both [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addition) (1129 questions) and [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/add) (3460 questions) mean the same thing, a mathematical operation. Do we really need both tags?

Wiki for [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addition):

> Addition is a mathematical operation that represents combining collections of objects together into a larger collection. It is signified by the plus sign (+).

Wiki for [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/add):

> Addition is a mathematical operation that represents combining collections of objects together into a larger collection. It is signified by the plus sign (+).

The latter is sometimes abused to mean lots of things, from [adding values to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651539/update-item-in-dynamodb-add-new-item-to-the-end), through [adding CSS to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922329/how-to-add-css-to-a-html-gmail-message) to [adding users in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397227/django-create-user-crashes?r=SearchResults&s=2|33.1489). Maybe it should be burninated instead?

Comment: Do we really need a tag for an arithmetic operation?

Answer (score 2):

The two tag excerpts are the same - and [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=lL0zXaKyB5agvQSIxZHgAg&q=Addition+is+a+mathematical+operation+that+represents+combining+collections+of+objects+together+into+a+larger+collection.+It+is+signified+by+the+plus+sign+%28%2B%29.&oq=Addition+is+a+mathematical+operation+that+represents+combining+collections+of+objects+together+into+a+larger+collection.+It+is+signified+by+the+plus+sign+%28%2B%29.&gs_l=psy-ab.3...277.277..557...0.0..0.263.263.2-1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....0.9v7ZqzaWXnQ&ved=0ahUKEwiizPX768TjAhUWUI8KHYhiBCwQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) it throws up tons of word-for-word results, leading me to believe it was plagiarised in both tags, in the original revision. Even the body of the wiki - the explanation, which is usually large enough (esp. in larger tags - [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), etc.) to avoid duplication - has been copied *word-for-word* across both tags by two different users.

And people usually don't care which one of these they use - [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/add) is preferred, but some are tagged with [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/add+addition) (only 15, but still - absolutely no reason to tag the same mathematical operation twice).

These two tags should **absolutely**, most certainly be synonimised - usually the smaller is thrown in with the larger, so if any users that have 5 score or more in [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/add) (or [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addition) - it doesn't really matter) could suggest a synonym, and get it approved (maybe moderators could help), then it would clear this little area up.

#### Kind of related - feature request (ish)

On a side note, since we have quite a few mathematical tags, and many other tags that belong to "families" (all the jQuery and Angular tags and versions for instance (*make it stop!*)), we could create these tag families, used for classification of extremely similar tags - so we don't have to go digging for the extremely rare ECMAScript 4 tag, we could just go to the JavaScript tag family, and bam! ES4 would finally be revealed as nonexistent.

Comment: "*many other tags that belong to "families"*" - there was a feature request for having hierarchical tags. I can't look for it right now but it sounds like what you're describing. Basically, some tags do belong in groups and in a lot of cases there is a parent sort of concept, like `javascript` -> `jquery` for example. So, expressing that hierarchy would be useful in categorising tags. Same thing with `mathematics` -> `addition` and `subtraction`. Although the whole "hierarchy" is a very tricky concept. Not sure if the FR was declined or not but it seems hard to implement.